# iOS NSString to NSURL results to null pointer?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

This is working for me:

```
NSURL *u1 = [NSURL alloc];
u1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.0.50/upload.php?file=test.png" relativeToURL:nil];
```

But When i am getting it from an http request:

```
NSString* imageRemoteUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *u1 = [NSURL alloc];
u1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageRemoteUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I get the this:

```
http://10.0.0.50/upload.php?file=test.png%0A
```

with %0A at the end.

Comment: Have u checked string? Make sure there is nothing like space after .png

Comment: `%0A` is percent encoded newline character

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
NSString* trimmedUrlString = [imageRemoteUrl stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSURL *u1 = [NSURL URLWithString:trimmedUrlString];
```

Answer (score 0):

*%0A* is the URL encoded version of the new line character *\n*, so you should make sure to remove it from your string.

As a side note, you can remove the calls to `[NSURL alloc]` as you are replacing the allocated variable in the next line.

Comment: The application crashes if i remove %0A fro the URL. This is how i download the image: 
     `code` NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
           timeoutInterval:60.0];
 
 `code` connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate: self];

Comment: How are you removing %0A that causes the crash? Could you share the crash message please? And what exactly is in `data`? The image you just received?

Comment: imageRemoteUrl __NSCFString * @"http://10.0.0.50/upload.php?file=test.png\n". Data is NSMutableData* data. But this should work why is it working when URL is hard coded?